# How to use rte_hash_add_key_data?

Tags: c

I write a program based on DPDK,I am not familiar with dpdk hash library,so I write an example about DPDK hash.The code is:

```
struct rte_hash *hash;
struct rte_hash_parameters params;
void *data;
int key;
int d;
int ret;
bzero (&params,sizeof (params));

params.name = NULL;
params.entries = 500;
params.key_len = sizeof (int);
params.hash_func = rte_jhash;
params.hash_func_init_val = 0;

hash = rte_hash_create (&params);
if (!hash) {
    fprintf (stderr,"rte_hash_create failed\n");
    return;
}   

key = 0;
data = NULL;
key = 1;  
d = 1;
//add 1/1 to hash table
rte_hash_add_key_data (hash,&key,(void *) (long) d); 
key = 2;
d = 2;
//add 2/2 to hash table
rte_hash_add_key_data (hash,&key,(void *) (long) d); 

key = 2;
//I want to lookup with key = 2
//But it failed.
ret = rte_hash_lookup_data (hash,&key,&data);
if (ret) {
    if (ret == ENOENT) {
        fprintf (stderr,"find failed\n");
        return;
    }   

    if (ret == EINVAL) {
        fprintf (stderr,"parameter invalid");
        return;
    }
    fprintf (stderr,"lookup failed");
    return;
}
```

In the code above, I add 1/1 and 2/2 to hash table.
but rte_hash_lookup_data with key = 2 failed.How to deal with this problem?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation for this function appears to be a bit misleading.  It says that it will return ret=0 on success, but all of the code examples show that you should check for:
`(ret < 0)`

See for example
http://dpdk.org/doc/api/examples_2ipsec-secgw_2ipsec_8c-example.html#a2 where they check to make sure ret is non-negative.

```
ret = rte_hash_lookup_data (hash,&key,&data);
if (ret < 0) {  /* CHANGE THIS LINE */
    //.... continue
```

When I ran your code and printed the value for the returned `void *data`, it printed `2` as expected with return value of `1`.  Since error values are negative and you receive a positive number, I am guessing that the documentation for `rte_hash_lookup_data` should read more similarly to the documentation for `rte_hash_lookup`.

So your lookup/set code is correct, you just need to change your `ret` value check.

Comment: can anyone tell me when rte_hash_lookup_data() returns 0? (dpdk 20.08)